# how to set path to php with min32w

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I'm running min32 on win7 on a flash drive named e: . My php interpreter is at e:\EasyPHP-12.1\php\php546x130717222153\php.exe.

I'm trying to download php-composer into a project using:

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

but this gives:

```
sh.exe": php.exe: command not found
```

how can I set the path to php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first `php` in your command line with the full path of your php: `e:\EasyPHP-12.1\php\php546x130717222153\php.exe` - that should probably do the trick, no matter in which directory you are.

Another method would be to actually add that path (without `php.exe`) to the shell path. You should be able to find out how to do that with stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+path+to+windows+environment

Comment: Thanks, In my case I had to put quotes around the full path ( "e:\EasyPHP-12.1\php\php546x130717222153\php.exe" )